# Filter for range queries on a set

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, dictionary, bloom-filter

We have a set S of keys.

For membership queries (is k in S?), bloom filters often help us quickly determine that a key is not in the set.

How can we filter range queries (is there a key from the range [k1,k2] in S?) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem in time O(log n) using either Segment Trees or Fenwick Trees.

With segment trees, you can ask the question is there a bit-set in the range [a..b]? This question can be answered in time O(log n). Also, you can set (or unset) a single bit in time O(log n).

Similarly with Fenwick Trees.

Assumption: Keys k1, k2, etc... are integers - we must make this assumption so that we can make sense of the range [k1..k2].

Comment: B-trees, or any other search tree, also let you answer range queries in O(log n).

Comment: @IritKatriel True, but they are mostly for on-disk. When the user mentioned "filter" I thought it was primarily meant for in-memory filtering where false positives are okay (like bloom filters). Plus, for a "filter" data structure, memory usage is important - Fenwick Trees have a low memory footprint whereas B-Trees would have a much larger one - because of wasted space in the nodes.

Comment: @IritKatriel Again, if you know the range to be in a static range, you can also use vEB Trees - these have a cost of O(lg lg n) per dictionary operation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control of the length of the ranges you want to test? If the range is small (k2 - k1 < some smallish number), then you could just use the bloom filter from before and check each k in the range.

Comment: True, but I don't have a small bound on the ranges.

Comment: If you know the distribution of values (linear, logarithmic, etc...) then you can compress your ranges and do approximate set membership testing using Fenwick Trees. This will reduce your search space a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can make testing multiple values faster by making sure the low order byte / bits of one of the hashes are passed through the hash function intact.

E.g. you have hash function f(x) and hash function g(x).  You define f(x) such that f(x) = hash_function(x div 16) + x mod 16.

When you search, you can search the 2 bytes (16 bits) surrounding the f(x) result for a 1 bit.  If you find one, test the corresponding value for a hit.

This means that you can search for matches 16 values at a time with a fast two-byte retrieval.

Note that playing with the hash functions this way may affect your results in other ways.